# Why is this code from Ruby book not working?

Tags: ruby

I copied this out of a book. "The Ultimate Guide to Ruby Programming" 
Copyright (c) 2006-2016 Satish Talim http://satishtalim.com/

Please see the code and error message. Why am I getting this error?

I have checked my typing, re-entered the code, exited irb re-entered irb, re-entered the code, same result. What is my error?

```
irb(main):001:0> 10.times do |num|
irb(main):002:1*   square = num * num
irb(main):003:1>   return num, square
irb(main):004:1> end
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/irb.cmd:19:in `<main>'
        3: from (irb):1
        2: from (irb):1:in `times'
        1: from (irb):3:in `block in irb_binding'
LocalJumpError (unexpected return)
irb(main):005:0>
```

Comment: What book provided that code sample, so I can be sure never to recommend it?

Comment: I would like to second anotherm's comment. Please, tell us what book this is, so we can warn others. This code has not worked since at least Ruby 1.8, which was released in 2003 and end-of-lifed in 2013. (In fact, I don't think this code has *ever* worked in *any* version of Ruby, and even if it *did* work, it wouldn't do what the code tries to do.)

Comment: The book is " The Ultimate Guide to Ruby Programming" 
 
Copyright (c) 2006-2016 Satish Talim http://satishtalim.com/

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear where this is intended to be used, but you can't `return` like that inside a loop.

The code is probably:

```
def squared
  10.times do |num|
    square = num * num

    yield num, square
  end
end
```

Where you'd call that somehow externally:

```
squared do |num, square|
  puts "The square of #{num} is #{square}"
end
```

A simplified version of this code is:

```
def square(num)
  return num * num
end
```

Where here `return` is in a valid context. Ruby tends to avoid explicit `return` statements *unless it's intentional to avoid running the remainder of the method*, as in:

```
 def square(num)
   if (num > 1000)
     return "That number is way too big!"
   end

   num * num
 end
```

Here the last statement to run (`num * num`) is the *implicit return value* of the method. Many blocks work this way, even `if`, where in Ruby `if` statements return values:

```
choice = if (num > 10)
  "big"
else
  "small"
end
```

Where `choice` ends up being either of those two strings depending on conditions.

Comment: In addition, I'd say that a common use of returns is the use of a guard clause e.g. in the example here, `return "That number is way too big!" if num > 100`

Comment: @Yule That's another approach I've seen commonly but I try and avoid what I call "surprise conditions", as in trailing `if` or `unless` at the end of lines long enough you might not realize they're there due to being clipped out of the window. As a general rule anything non-trivial, beyond `return false if x`, gets the multi-line treatment so it's abundantly clear that it's a conditional `return` and the conditions are easily observed.

Answer (score -2):

`return` is used inside methods. You are using it without one.

Try the following:

```
def get_my_result
    10.times do |num|
        square=num*num
        return num,square
    end
end

get_my_result()
```

Note: With this code, the loop will execute only once and return the value [0, 0]

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Comment: I agree that using camelcase in function is not the convention in Ruby. But it will not cause an error.

Comment: It's very strongly discouraged. [Rubocop](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop) will give you a citation for doing this.

Comment: "`return` is used inside functions" – This is wrong. There are no functions in Ruby. There are methods, blocks, lambda literals, modules, classes, and scripts, but no functions.

Comment: @tadman that is correct. Rubycop will give a citation. What I meant is that it will not affect the functionality of the code. Thank you for the note, I updated my answer.

Comment: @JörgWMittag . Thank you for the note. Yes Ruby has only methods, not functions. But I think everyone read my answer did understand what I'm pointing at. And that's the main purpose of my answer. updated my answer though for accuracy.

Comment: It might seem like a little thing but your original code read like Ruby code written by someone with a Python or JavaScript accent. Expressing it in true Ruby form is especially important for educational contexts like this one. Thanks for making the fix.

Comment: Please select the one and only answer to date if you found it helpful.